# How do I run MySQL database as a tracker store for Rasa server?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, rasa

endpoints.yml

```
tracker_store:
    type: SQL
    dialect: "mysql"  # the dialect used to interact with the db
    url: "127.0.0.1:3306"  # (optional) host of the sql db, e.g. "localhost"
    db: "rasa"  # path to your db
    username: "*****" # username used for authentication
    password: "*****"
```

I am using docker-compose to run the Rasa server.

```
version: '3'
services:
  rasa:
    image: rasa/rasa:1.10.8-full
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - "5005:5005"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: ["run", "--enable-api", "--cors", "*", "--debug"]
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - .data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "*****"
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "No"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: rasa
    ports:
      - "3306"
  app:
    image: rasa_actions:latest
    expose:
    - "5055"
```

I've also tried replacing the dialect with mysql+pymysql or postgresql. The former gives a module error and the latter gives a connection error, despite the database being normally accessible.

I have read online that there is some issue with MySQL and Rasa. I need some clarification with how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Which error message do you see?
In general, we recommend to use `pymysql` as a dialect.

Comment: So in my local computer I had pymyql so it worked but in the Ubuntu VM it said MySQLDB module not found and moved on to inmemory tracker store. I have given up and decided use postgresql because I read somewhere that the docker image of rasa does not support MySQL yet.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).